# How to make a click on R Leaflet state go to a url?

Tags: html, r, json, url, leaflet

I'd like to build a map where when a state is clicked, it will open a hyperlink url in a new tab. I've been searching around for answers and can't quite get it to work for r leaflet. I believe I need to edit the json in the `onRender` but it seems I'm not doing it right.

Thanks so much!!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tigris)
library(leaflet)

state <-
    states(
        cb = TRUE
    ) %>% 
    filter(STUSPS %in% c('CA', 'WA', 'MD')) %>% 
    mutate(win_url = 
        case_when(
            STUSPS == 'CA' ~ str_c('<a href=https://shiny.demog.berkeley.edu/alexramiller/kqed-evictions/>California Evictions</a>'), 
            STUSPS == 'WA' ~ str_c('<a href=https://evictions.study/washington/maps/summary.html>Washington Evictions</a>'), 
            STUSPS == 'MD' ~ str_c('<a href=https://evictions.study/maryland/report/baltimore.html>Maryland Evictions</a>')))

leaflet(state) %>% 
    addMapPane(name = "polygons", zIndex = 410) %>% 
    addMapPane(name = "maplabels", zIndex = 420) %>% # higher zIndex rendered on top
    htmlwidgets::onRender('function onclick(e) {
    window.open(e.target.feature.properties.win_url);
        }') %>% 
    addProviderTiles("CartoDB.PositronNoLabels") %>%
    addProviderTiles("CartoDB.PositronOnlyLabels", 
                   options = leafletOptions(pane = "maplabels"),
                   group = "map labels") %>%
    addPolygons(
        # label = ~'<a href="https://shiny.demog.berkeley.edu/alexramiller/kqed-evictions/">California Evictions</a>', # this is an option but not preferred
        fillOpacity = .5, 
        color = ~'Red', 
        stroke = TRUE, 
        weight = 1, 
        opacity = .5, 
        highlightOptions = highlightOptions(
                    color = "#ff4a4a", 
                    weight = 5,
                    bringToFront = TRUE
                    )
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the answer from [Clicking a leaflet marker takes you to URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58210783/clicking-a-leaflet-marker-takes-you-to-url?answertab=votes#tab-top) and looping through, from [addEventListener using for loop and passing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586137/addeventlistener-using-for-loop-and-passing-values), seems to work:

```
jsCode <- paste0('
 function(el, x, data) {
  var marker = document.getElementsByClassName("leaflet-interactive");
  for(var i=0; i < marker.length; i++){
    (function(){
      var v = data.win_url[i];
      marker[i].addEventListener("click", function() { window.open(v);}, false);
  }()); 
  }
 }
')
```

And run

```
leaflet(state) %>% 
    addMapPane(name = "polygons", zIndex = 410) %>% 
    addMapPane(name = "maplabels", zIndex = 420) %>% 
     addProviderTiles("CartoDB.PositronNoLabels") %>%
     addProviderTiles("CartoDB.PositronOnlyLabels", 
                    options = leafletOptions(pane = "maplabels"),
                    group = "map labels") %>%
  addPolygons(
        fillOpacity = .5, 
        color = 'Red', 
        stroke = TRUE, 
        weight = 1, 
        opacity = .5, 
        highlightOptions = highlightOptions(
                    color = "#ff4a4a", 
                    weight = 5,
                    bringToFront = TRUE
                    )  
        )  %>%
  htmlwidgets::onRender(jsCode, data=state)
```

I had to rejig the state URLs

```
state <-
    states(
        cb = TRUE
    ) %>% 
    filter(STUSPS %in% c('CA', 'WA', 'MD')) %>% 
    mutate(win_url = 
        case_when(
            STUSPS == 'CA' ~ 'https://shiny.demog.berkeley.edu/alexramiller/kqed-evictions/', 
            STUSPS == 'WA' ~ 'https://evictions.study/washington/maps/summary.html', 
            STUSPS == 'MD' ~ 'https://evictions.study/maryland/report/baltimore.html'))
```

Comment: You are amazing user20650! Thank you so much!